# Manga where the main character is a dragon and human who dies and goes into another body after healing it

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga that I read a year ago.

The main character was a prince who is dragon and human. His father found him and punished him for a reason I can't remember.  The prince dies and goes into a boy that had died from breaking his neck on the edge of furniture (a desk). Then the prince uses these orbs around him (mana in the air) to make his neck better.

Later in the series some huge buff guy too was killing the main character over and over again because the big buff guy kept breaking all of his toys when he was little. Since the main character didn't break, he wanted to have him but failed.

I believe this was in full color.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any idea what site you read this on?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this (even after trying to fix the formatting). Can you explain the parts you remember in more detail?

Comment: Is this a reverse isekai story? It sounds like the father kills the protagonist and s/he wakes up as a human. You used "their" father; does the father confront multiple people (brother and sister, perhaps?), or is this a genderless "their"? "the boy uses manga in the air" - is that supposed to be magic?

Comment: @Laurel sorry for answering late i remember that the main character was a prince i know that much and that his father found him and he punished him for a reason i cant remember but the prince dies goes into a boy that had died from breaking his neck on the edge of furniture and then the prince uses these orbs around him to make his neck better then later in the series some huge guy buff too was killing the main character over and over again because the big buff guy kept breaking all of his toys when he was little but since the main character didn't break he wanted to have him but failed