# Looking for manga/web toon maybe : reincarnated/isekai/body swap? Mc into a dead kid

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m looking for a manga and or web toon. I can’t remember if it was colored or not, but I remember a little about the beginning, like how the main character’s (mc is a guy btw) father kills his son and then the son's soul gets put into a kid but that kid was dead (apparently he fell and snapped his neck on a table's edge). The soul of the mc goes into the body of dead kid, then when the mc realizes the neck is broken he uses orbs of magic around the room to heal it and honestly that’s all I remember. Thank you.

Comment: *"The main character gets reborn into the body of someone with a broken (neck-back) and gets into alot of fights. He gets beat to a bloddy pulp most of the time but doesn't die. I believe in one of the chapters his neck is broken and he flips it back around."* _-  https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1482816&show=7360

Comment: Does looking at [Manga where the main character is a dragon and human who dies and goes into another body after healing it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/272284/82909) remind you of any details? I think they might be the same story.

Comment: @Laurel actually yes this is the same story that Im trying to find i dont know if it was a dragon but it sounds very similar thank you